# How to say if a curve is flat?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a curve
 $\omega$ :
 $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c} 
X=t-1 \\ 
Y=t^2-2t \\ 
Z=t^2-3t+1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Which way can i use to prove if such a curve like $\omega$ is flat ? And what does it means geometrically?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$ x-y+z = (t-1)-(t^2-2t)+(t^2-3t+1) =0$$

Thus the points $(x,y,z)$ are on the plane $$x-y+z=0$$ for all values of $t$

That means your curve is on a flat plane, so it is flat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing "flat" means that the curve lies on a plane.

**HINT:** A set of points lies on a plane if and only if the coordinates $(x, y, z)$ of such points satisfy some linear relation of the kind:
$$ Ax + By + Cz + D = 0 $$
Where $A, B, C, D$ are constants. Can you show this is true for your curve?

Comment: You mean : substitute p ( t-1 , $ t^2-2t $ , $ t^2-3t+1 ) in the equation of a plane and solve for t ?

Comment: You don't have to solve for t. You are correct in saying that you should substitute, but then you have to find the four constants.